# How to convert byte[] Array format Images into H.264 video compression format to push to AWS Kinesis Video stream

Tags: java, arrays, amazon-web-services, video-streaming, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I'm developing application and will be getting continuous byte[] format images and need to convert to H.264 video compression video and need to push to AWS Kinesis Video stream.

Could you please let me know how we can do it in Java or is there any available SDK/Plugin which ca n used to push the data.